# In ECS, how to mount container's user home and host's user home?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

In ECS, how can I mount volumes the container's userhome and host's user home?

```
"containerDefinitions": [
{
"name": "web",
"image": "nginx",
"cpu": 99,
"memory": 100,
"portMappings": [
{
"containerPort": 80,
"hostPort": 80
}
],
"essential": true,
"mountPoints": [
{
"sourceVolume": "webdata",
"containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html"
}
]
}
]
```